# SQL Query SELECT same data from different tables, show all records, but show / display matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have two tables where I would like to compare information (In order to get from the initial table to the other I need to go through a reference table).
I am getting the results I am looking for except when a match is found an extra row of data is added (screen shot below). There should be only 4 rows, I don't understand why the value in column 1 row 5 wasn't just added to column 1 row 4.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Code**

```
Select DISTINCT
 CASE
    WHEN LIC.ORDER_NUM = LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER THEN LIC.ORDER_NUM 
    ELSE ''
END 'ORDER Number 1',
LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER 'ORDER Number 2'
from LN_TABLE1 LN_STLIC 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LN_REF LN_PDE_RTN on LN_STLIC.LNPID = LN_PDE_RTN.LNPID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LN_TABLE2 LIC on LN_PDE_RTN.ID = LIC.ID 
where LIC.ID = '123456'
```

**Example Table Data**

LN_TABLE1

[image]

LN_REF

[image]

LN_TABLE2

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What do you mean "added to"?  You are using `select` distinct and you are getting distinct rows.  (3) Your `where` clause is turning the outer joins into inner joins, so your query is confusing.

Comment: Provide some sample data of your tables

Comment: @GordonLinoff, There is more than one unique ID in LN_REF, LN_TABLE1 & LN_TABLE2. In an attempt to scale down the number of results I included the WHERE clause so I could show an example

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `Order Number 1` as

```
CASE
    WHEN LIC.ORDER_NUM = LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER THEN LIC.ORDER_NUM 
    ELSE ''
END
```

So, you can reasonably infer that when `Order Number 1` is blank, it's because `LIC.ORDER_NUM` doesn't match `LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER`.

You asked for a DISTINCT on the combination of `Order Number 1` and `Order Number 2`.  So every **combination** of the two of them that appears in the data, will appear just once.

Because `LN_TABLE1` has four different order numbers for the same value of `LNPID`, you're going to generate 3 records with a blank `Order Number 1` and `Order Number 2` set to 210414.  But the `distinct` will take it down to just one, plus the one where they match (records 4 and 5 in your example).

You'd probably have to join on `LIC.ORDER_NUM = LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER` in order to match the order numbers to each other, and get only 1 record for  order number `210414`.

I could give you a better query if I knew a bit more about what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response.... I understand your description, the end goal is to get the results to looks like what I put in my initial question, except remove row 4. I.e. Show all the results from LN_TABLE1 but when there is a match from LN_TABLE1 display it on the same row. If I remove the DISTINCT, it get even more results i.e. all the combinations of both columns

Comment: Based on this and your dbfiddle entry, it looks like you have an extra record in your source tables -- probably in LN_REF or LN_TABLE2. (I know it doesn't appear in your screen shots, but that's the most likely explanation.)

Comment: One way to track it down would be to add the extra fields from the various tables -- the IDs and raw order numbers -- to your query, and see what appears for that unwanted row.

Comment: In fact, I would bet it's in LN_TABLE2. Let me know if I'm right!

Comment: (I'm assuming that your source tables are NOT being created on the fly, like they are on dbfiddle!  That they already exist and have real data!)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct... there is an extra record in LN_TABLE2 that I didn't initially see... I added the value in the dbfiddle entry and I get the same results....https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42677c26aa3814d0e3fa8214e06b78dc

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Does this clean up the problem?  If so, consider marking my answer as your accepted answer.  If not, please let us know what still needs to be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing:

We can do a simple LEFT JOIN with LN_STLIC and LIC :

```
Select CASE WHEN LN_STLIC.order_number = LIC.order_num THEN LIC.ORDER_NUM END ORD 
Number1, LN_STLIC.order_number ORD Number2
from LN_TABLE1 LN_STLIC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LN_TABLE2 LIC ON LN_STLIC.order_number = LIC.order_num;
```

Also doing the below also gets you the same things in case you want to use LIC.ID = '1234' and there is no need to use DISTINCT.

```
Select
CASE WHEN LIC.ORDER_NUM = LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER THEN LIC.ORDER_NUM 
ELSE ''
END ORD_NBR_1,
LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER ORD_NBR_2
from #LN_TABLE1 LN_STLIC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #LN_REF LN_PDE_RTN on LN_STLIC.LNPID = LN_PDE_RTN.LNPID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #LN_TABLE2 LIC on LN_PDE_RTN.ID = LIC.ID AND 
LN_STLIC.ORDER_NUMBER =LIC.ORDER_NUM 
;
```

Comment: I get the results I am looking for when I enter my data into the follow site
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ddf2d6bbf470a49c1b0237d7abdf7865

Comment: No... on the site, I get the results I am looking for. But when running the same query locally in SSMS I get the results shown in my original question... very odd

Comment: When I use your second suggestion (removing the distinct) I get far more results i.e. every combination or the two columns.

Comment: However, it works just fine without DISTINCT here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=339d3d002a6694eb93882053dafb4563. I believe we are missing something here. There could be 1 more extra row in the 1st table in your actual DB.

Comment: Yes, there was extra data in my source table LN_TABLE2 that I did not account for initially I added it in my initial dbfiddle entry and am not getting the same results in both dbfiddle and SSMS
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42677c26aa3814d0e3fa8214e06b78dc

Comment: Try this one: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5472fd18df718e53527aed39f4209947